I made up a new set of numbers. Does it cause any paradoxes?
I was in Algebra 2 class the other day learning about complex numbers, and I wondered what would happen if I made up a new set of numbers for multiplying/diving zeros (I know there is like a trillion paradoxes that go with dividing by zero but trust me). I represented the zeros with the cyrillic ю, so $4×0=4ю$, and $0×0=ю²$. That would also mean that $4÷0$ would equal $4ю^-1$.
So anyways, I tested it out on a limit function and it worked. I found this function on a Wikipedia article (I forgot which one but luckily I wrote it down):
$$ \text{Lim}_{\Delta\to 0} \frac{f(x+Δx)-f(x)}{Δx}=\text{(the slope of a function)}$$
Usually the problem here is dividing by zero but the set of numbers I made up fixes that. Im gonna find the slope of $f(x)=x²$ at $x=4$: $$((4+4ю)²-(4)²)/4ю, (16+32ю+16ю²-16)/4ю, (32ю+16ю²)/4ю, 8+4ю.$$ Since $ю$ just equals $0$ you can write it as $8+4×0$, which equals $8$. $8$ is the correct answer there. I think this method is pretty intuitive, but I am taking an Algebra 2 course so I wanted to ask professional mathematicians if there are any problems with it.

Can you explain how you mean this set of numbers 'fixes' dividing by zero? You've replaced zero with another symbol, which doesn't permit dividing by it.

Then what would be $0 \div 0$ according to your notation?

It's good that you are thinking about these things and trying stuff out.  But what you've done here isn't any different from expanding the original expression with the $\Delta x$, doing the algebra the same way, and then replacing $\Delta x$ with $0$ at the end.   You've just written $ю$ in place of $\Delta x$.

Changing the symbol you use for $0$ cannot let you do more.  This should be obvious.  Anything broken by allowing division by $0$ will also be broken by allowing division by the new symbol.
That said, the essence of your example (a symbol that may be identified with $0$ when it is allowed) is that of nonstandard analysis.  For instance, in the hyperreals, we have infinite and infinitesimal elements.  If we write $\epsilon$ for an infinitesimal, then for $f(x) = x^2$ we may write $$\frac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon} = \frac{x^2+2\epsilon x + \epsilon^2 - x^2}{\epsilon} = 2x + \epsilon$$
This isn't equal to $2x$, but it's infinitesimally close to that value.  Since $2x$ is a real number and $2x+\epsilon$ is infinitesimally close to $2x$, we would say that the standard part of $2x+\epsilon$ is $2x$, or in symbols, $\text{st}(2x+\epsilon) = 2x$.  Put together, we have
$$f'(x) = \text{st}\left(\frac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon}\right).$$
Is this consistent?  Yes, at least with the usual consistency assumptions we have to make with standard mathematics.
Does it match what you have shown in your example?  As far as I'm concerned, yes.
Have we allowed division by zero?  No.

As a final note, it's not that "division by zero" is universally banned.  It's just that it breaks certain algebraic properties, so we only allow it when we gain more than we lose by allowing it.  As some other examples where we allow it: projective space, the Riemann sphere, some parts of integration theory, etc.
That said, as far as I know, in all such systems we disallow $\frac{0}{0}$ or equivalently $0 \cdot \frac{x}{0}$.  I've never seen a situation where defining these quantities is worthwhile.

Before we can definitely say what is wrong with this approach you need to give a clear definition of it.  How is your new character different from just trying to accept $0^{-1}$?  Early on you seem to say that ю is different from $0$, but at the end you say they are equal.  If they are equal, why make a new symbol?  How do we add, subtract, multiply, and divide with this new number?
If you can make the operations consistent you have defined a new number system.  Is it a field?  If so, you need to show it satisfies the field axioms.  If not, it may not be of much interest.  What problems does it let you solve?  The fact that not being allowed to divide by $0$ offends you does not count.  All mathematicians have invested a lot of time learning how to work with the standard real numbers.  If you want to convince them to invest time in understanding your new numbers you need to show that there is some advantage.
